# 415 Media Type is Unsupported for Multipart/Related or multipart/form-data in C#(ASMX) WS

Tags: c#, android, multipartform-data, android-ksoap2, http-status-code-415

I have been using WS build on `C#` to send `SOAP objects from Android application using KSOAP2 jar file.`
Currently my requirement is to **send Image File(s) along with the SOAP Object** in the same request.

I do have found that my request should look a like : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996427.aspx this.

But the server always returns error **code 415**.

I have also verified MIME Types in my Windows Server, in the list there is no type as Multipart/Related but still when sending only 4 image files to the same server without SOAP Object in a different WS method it does accepts the request and read the files.

Even I have tried to call that WS using SOAPUI and added attachment but the response keep saying 415.

I want to know that:

> What are the possible chances of errors? How can we determine that our
>   WS method is capable of Accepting multipart requests?

Comment: 415 = Unsupported media type

Comment: What @maven I know that, Please tell me if you know any clue about `How can we determine that our WS method is capable of Accepting multipart requests?`